# Font Awesome icons disappeared. Strange characters (Big Commerce)

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, bigcommerce

After doing a few and simple css edits on a Big Commerce site, the search and cart icons suddenly disappeared. They are now displayed as strange characters.
I went into the Big Commerce design backend and did not find anything strange into the code. When inspect the html and css code in the browser the icons are called properly:

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

What could be wrong? Url to the site is [Url](http://hearneseed.com/)
template demo url is [enter link description here](http://california-demo.mybigcommerce.com/)

Any help is much appreciated, new to Big Commerce.

Comment: Does your browser have adblock?

Comment: The console says, "Error: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/s-aozh7/templates/__custom/Styles/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3
Source File: http://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/s-aozh7/templates/__custom/Styles/styles.css?t=1464079596
Line: 4857, Column: 12

Comment: Thanks I don't use Adblock

Comment: @ Mr Lister I didn't inspect the console. So based on your message it seems the font awesome files need to be added to: /templates/__custom/Styles/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3 Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when you edit CSS files for the first time. If you download all the theme files and reupload the font-awesome or font folder to WebDAV, that should resolve.

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks so much! The font folder along with its files were missing into /styles/ so I upload the files with CyberDuck.

Comment: Not a problem. We see this almost every time and I believe we have a support document on it. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thanks again so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from console.

[image]

> Font from origin '[http://cdn4.bigcommerce.com](http://cdn4.bigcommerce.com/)' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '[http://hearneseed.com](http://hearneseed.com/)' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

You're linking to a file that does not exist on the server. Also you may want to read up on the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)!

[Here's](http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css) the official link to the [Font-Awesome library](http://fontawesome.io/). (Don't hyperlink! Download it, host it on your server and link to it that way!)

> http://fontawesome.io/
>   http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css