# font awesome shows weird characters (not squares)

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

sometimes font awesome shows weird characters when you hit the page. Refreshing the page is one fix but sometimes it is not. You need to hard refresh to fix it. 
I checked from developer console and I didn't see any errors. When I check the page css and fonts are loading correctly.

I'm using font awesome like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-hourglass-start fa-2x"></i>
or
<i class="fa fa-eye fa-2x"></i>
or
<i class="fa fa-ban"></i>
```

Here is how it looks like.
[image]

Comment: Could you include the code you are using to add the icon in your question?

Comment: Did these answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420929/font-awesome-icons-disappeared-strange-characters-big-commerce   and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376875/font-awesome-showing-asian-signs-instead-of-icons

Comment: Yea, I tried those before and yesterday too, but no change :( It's really weird.

Comment: Can you show the lines within `<head>` that deal with FontAwesome? Also: does this happen on a specific browser (version?) or across Chrome,FF,Edge etc.?